# how to set a PATH of ProofPower in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: desktop-environments, environment-variables

Respected Fellows,

I am using a formal verification tool ProofPower in Ubuntu 12.04, but i don't that how can i set a PATH or environment variables in Ubuntu 12.04.

My ProofPower bin path is : /home/username/pp/bin/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy: the line you need is simply

```
export VARIABLE=VALUE
```

in your case

```
export PATH=$PATH::/home/username/pp/bin/
```

the meaning should be straightforward: you're adding an entry to your PATH.
you may want to add it to your shell configuration file .bashrc (or .zshrc) if you want to change just one user's PATH, and otherwise you may want to have a look at general configuration files such as /etc/profile.